# What's wrong with "time.sleep(length)"?

Tags: python, syntax

What is the problem by line 84? I've got this error:

> SyntaxError: time.sleep(length)

What's wrong with my code?

```
    import time 
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    buzzer_pin = 17
    sensor_pin = 18 

    GPIO.setup(sensor_pin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(buzzer_pin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(buzzer_pin, GPIO.OUT) 

    notes = {
     'B0' : 31,
     'C1' : 33, 'CS1' : 35,
     'D1' : 37, 'DS1' : 39,
     'EB1' : 39,
     'E1' : 41,
     'F1' : 44, 'FS1' : 46, 
     'G1' : 49, 'GS1' : 52,  
     'A1' : 55, 'AS1' : 58,
     'BB1' : 58,  
     'B1' : 62, 
     'C2' : 65, 'CS2' : 69,
     'D2' : 73, 'DS2' : 78,
     'EB2' : 78,
     'E2' : 82,
     'F2' : 87, 'FS2' : 93,
     'G2' : 98, 'GS2' : 104,
     'A2' : 110, 'AS2' : 117,
     'BB2' : 123,
     'B2' : 123,
     'C3' : 131, 'CS3' : 139,
     'D3' : 147, 'DS3' : 156,
     'EB3' : 156,
     'E3' : 165,
     'F3' : 175, 'FS3' : 185,
     'G3' : 196, 'GS3' : 208,
     'A3' : 220, 'AS3' : 233,
     'BB3' : 233,
     'B3' : 247,
     'C4' : 262, 'CS4' : 277,
     'D4' : 294, 'DS4' : 311,
     'EB4' : 311,
     'E4' : 330,
     'F4' : 349, 'FS4' : 370,
     'G4' : 392, 'GS4' : 415,
     'A4' : 440, 'AS4' : 466,
     'BB4' : 466,
     'B4' : 494,
     'C5' : 523, 'CS5' : 554,
     'D5' : 587, 'DS5' : 622,
     'EB5' : 622,
     'E5' : 659,
     'F5' : 698, 'FS5' : 740,
     'G5' : 784, 'GS5' : 831,
     'A5' : 880, 'AS5' : 932,
     'BB5' : 932,
     'B5' : 988,
     'C6' : 1047, 'CS6' : 1109,
     'D6' : 1175, 'DS6' : 1245,
     'EB6' : 1245,
     'E6' : 1319,
     'F6' : 1397, 'FS6' : 1480,
     'G6' : 1568, 'GS6' : 1661,
     'A6' : 1760, 'AS6' : 1865,
     'BB6' : 1865,
     'B6' : 1976,
     'C7' : 2093, 'CS7' : 2217,
     'D7' : 2349, 'DS7' : 2489,
     'EB7' : 2489,
     'E7' : 2637,
     'F7' : 2794, 'FS7' : 2960,
     'G7' : 3136, 'GS7' : 3322,
     'A7' : 3520, 'AS7' : 3729,

     'BB7' : 3729,
     'B7' : 3951,
     'C8' : 4186, 'CS8' : 4435,
     'D8' : 4699, 'DS8' : 4978
    }

    def buzz(frequency, length):

     if(frequency==0):
     time.sleep(length)
     return
     period = 1.0 / frequency
     delayValue = period / 2
     numCycles = int(length * frequency)

     for i in range(numCycles):
     GPIO.output(buzzer_pin, True)
     time.sleep(delayValue)
     GPIO.output(buzzer_pin, False)
     time.sleep(delayValue)

    def play():
     buzz(notes['A3'], 0.5)
     buzz(notes['A3'], 0.5)
     buzz(notes['A3'], 0.5)
     buzz(notes['F3'], 0.35)
     buzz(notes['C4'], 0.15)
     buzz(notes['A3'], 0.5)
     buzz(notes['F3'], 0.35)
     buzz(notes['C4'], 0.15)
     buzz(notes['A3'], 1.0)

    while True:
     if GPIO.input(sensor_pin):
     print("Ses Alarmi!")
     play()
     time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? This is not the way to ask a question. I had a hard time just bringing your question to a point where it was legible. Post a full traceback, including what the expected behaviour is, and what isn't working out for you. Simply saying "SyntaxError" doesn't give anything for us to go on.

Comment: To begin with, you have indentation errors. Please fix your indentation and post something that would run.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
 if(frequency==0):
 time.sleep(length)
```

You need to indent the block after the `if`

```
 if(frequency==0):
     time.sleep(length)
```